# Assigning Delegation for a splitViewController where the masterController is housed in a Container View

Tags: ios, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller

I need help programmatically traversing a storyboard hierarchy.  This image should give some context: [storyboard](http://imgur.com/CGSDjuu).  The hierarchy consists of a splitViewController for which the master is a tabViewController with three tabs. The first tab contains two container views, the lower view being the 'problem child'.

I have had success traversing the hierarchy and assigning to the detailViewController the masterViewController as a delegate for tabs 2 and 3:

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    UITabBarController *masterTabBarController = [[splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
MasterViewController *masterViewController2 = [[masterTabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
MasterViewController *masterViewController3 = [[masterTabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];
masterViewController2.delegate = detailTableViewController;
masterViewController3.delegate = detailTableViewController;
```

However, tab 1 has been more irksome because of the container views.  My attempt has not worked and results in an index-out-of-bounds error:

```
UIViewController *containerViewController = [[masterTabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
MasterViewController *masterViewController1 = [[containerViewController childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
masterViewController1.delegate = detailTableViewController;
```

So instead of the AppDelegate, I've also tried two other routes within my MasterViewController itself:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.delegate = (DetailTableViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] presentedViewController];

//self.delegate = [[self.parentViewController.parentViewController.parentViewController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0]; Granted this should ONLY work for tab 1...but it doesnt.
}
```

But the uncommented line returns nil...

So I am hoping that some kind soul understands container views (as there is surprisingly little detail about these to be found) and how to access and assign a delegate to them via traversal, or some other technique.  There has to be a better way - what I have here is a very small app; I can't imagine having to individually walk the hierarchy of a complex app with dozens of screens.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There is no black magic when it comes to container and child view controllers. Your first solution looks OK to me provided that the children are linked properly to their parent. Since there are less than 2 objects in `[containerViewController childViewControllers]`, either your view controller hierarchy is not set up correctly, or `containerViewController` is not the object that you think it is. Can you please show more code how you walk the view controller hierarchy until you set the value of `containerViewController`?

Comment: wow, I did accidentally leave out this crucial line of code [will edit the question as well]:

`UIViewController *containerViewController = [[masterTabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];`

This line is the only missing code in the link from what I have posted previously.  It is of course intended to provide a reference to the UIView that houses the two container views, the lower container view being the one of concern.  So when I instantiate containerViewController I expect that calling `[[containerViewController childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:1]` would return what I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In attempt to find a solution to my problem, I tried to mimic my issue on a smaller scale in a brand new storyboard, making sure that all connections and code were set up appropriately.  Then it dawned on me as I was setting up the container views:

In storyboard, container views are automatically defined as "embed segues" and are not technically related to the screen in which they are housed.  Therefore, you cannot simply ask for the children of the 'parent' view and expect to get back an array of the container views.

So in order to pass data into and to define a delegate for the container views in question, I made a custom class for the view that housed the container views and ignored AppDelegate altogether.  In this class I defined a prepareForSegue function:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SingletonObject *data = [[SingletonObject alloc] init];

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"containerView1SegueID"])
    {

    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"tableEmbedSegue"])
    {
        MasterViewController *masterViewController0 = segue.destinationViewController;

        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:data.detailTableViewController];
        // ^ Or more specifically, 'masterViewController0.delegate = data.detailTableViewController;' would also work
    }
}
```

I hope this can help anyone who is having trouble with container views.  They are not children! They are embed segues.  Use prepareForSegue and you will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but I'm writing this as an answer because it gives me more space to elaborate.

Your code seems correct when compared to the image of the storyboard you provided. I am not used to storyboards, though, I prefer to set up everything programmatically, so I could be wrong. But: I made a quick test project where I'm trying to replicate your storyboard. I then copy&pasted ***your*** code to retrieve `masterViewController1` verbatim into my test project, and everything works perfectly!

Conclusion: Either something in your storyboard is set up the wrong way. Or something in your code that is not shown here unexpectedly changes the container/child relationships.

My advice: Review your storyboard. If you don't see the mistake, start a new storyboard from the ground up, maybe in a separate project. Start simple and verify each step. Once you arrive at the correct setup you can compare the new storyboard with the old one to find the mistake.

I know this is extremly general advice, but given the current situation I don't know what else you could do. Good luck.

Comment: Hey - I just want to say that I appreciated your feedback and that it was helpful, herzbube.  I'm going to answer my own question with my ultimate findings and also to give me a bit more space to expound.

Comment: @OneManBand Glad to hear that you found a solution. Keep on coding :-)